# how to post and get data with an html form in fb apps

Tags: html, facebook

I just created a simple facebook app. I would like to add a simple html form that posts values to the same file. I wrote the code below, but it doesn't work.

When I type something into the text box of the form and hit submit, the page reloads but it doesn't get any values.

I can't figure out how to post data to the fb app on a canvas page. I would be grateful if you could help me to fix my code. Thanks.

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '229924173724291',
        'secret' => '79e2bdaaa52bb3b80ea2f5e4c0f20d3e',
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } else {
        $loginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=229924173724291&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/tnxkapp/&scope=publish_stream";
        echo "<script>top.location.href=\"{$loginUrl}\"</script>";
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <? print($_POST[name]); ?>
        <form action="https://apps.facebook.com/tnxkapp/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php print($name); ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post to your actual app URL http://yourdomain.com/appfolder not the apps.facebook.com.  You're essentially trying to post info to facebook not your app with what your doing now.